# Error in this subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, subquery

This query:

```
left join (select tSpent, Customerid
from   (select SUM(spent) as tSpent, Customerid,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customerid ORDER BY Customerid DESC)
        from   Customer_Sales
        WHERE Customerid is not null)
              where   RN = 1) Sales ON Customer_Sales.Customerid = Data.Customerid
```

Is giving me an error on the `RN=1` line:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(select tSpent, Customerid
 from (select SUM(spent) as tSpent, Customerid,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customerid ORDER BY Customerid DESC)
        from   Customer_Sales
        WHERE Customerid is not null) t --use a alias for the derived table
 where RN = 1) Sales ON Customer_Sales.Customerid = Data.Customerid
```

Not sure why `row_number` is being used. You should also `group by customerid`.

The inner query could be simplified to

```
select SUM(spent) as tSpent, Customerid
from  Customer_Sales
WHERE Customerid is not null
group by customerid
```

as you are only trying to get the total spent for each customer.

Comment: I have a large view and I'm just trying to tack on a total for each customer id on the end.  Is there a simple reason the alias is required?

Comment: think of it this way `select * from tablename` where tablename in this case is your subquery. It should be named, because if you don't, it would be like saying `select * from ()`

Comment: Works much better, I had used row_number in a different query (where I just wanted the most recent record for that customer) and copied it over without rethinking. Works much better this way, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function was introduced in SQL Server 2005.  So you won't be able to make use of it.  You're also missing an alias for your subquery as vkp pointed out, and you can't use the alias you just assigned in `SELECT` within the `WHERE` clause (filtering happens before select, essentially).

Comment: Apologies, it is 2005, I had put the wrong version.